# After limiting numbers of characters after period/comma, I can't use comma on my device anymore

Tags: ios, swift

I was doing apps from Angela Yu Udemy course and that was bill calculator. Firstly I found out that my phone has comma instead of period, so I added this line :

`bill = Double( billAmount.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "."))!`

After that I noticed that I can use as many commas/periods as I want, so I found on OverFlow func that limits number of characters after period to two. After that I couldn't use my phone keyboard anymore, because I have a comma, and function includes periods as default input. Tried all I could but could not find a solution to that problem. If someone can help me I would be extremely thankful. Here I am including whole code :

```
import UIKit

class CalculatorViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    var tip = 0.0
    var bill = 0.0
    var numberOfPeople = 2
    var finalResult = "0.0"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var billTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var zeroPctButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tenPctButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var twentyPctButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var splitNumberLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        zeroPctButton.isSelected = false
        tenPctButton.isSelected = false
        twentyPctButton.isSelected = false
        
        billTextField.delegate = self
        billTextField.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    @IBAction func tipChanged(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        billTextField.endEditing(true)
        
        zeroPctButton.isSelected = false
        tenPctButton.isSelected = false
        twentyPctButton.isSelected = false
        sender.isSelected = true
        
        let buttonTitle = sender.currentTitle!
        let buttonTitleMinusPercentSign =  String(buttonTitle.dropLast())
        let buttonTitleAsANumber = Double(buttonTitleMinusPercentSign)!
        tip = buttonTitleAsANumber / 100
        
        
    }
    @IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        
        splitNumberLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", sender.value)
        numberOfPeople = Int(sender.value)
        
    }
    @IBAction func calculatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let billAmount = billTextField.text!
        if billAmount != "" {
            bill = Double( billAmount.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "."))!
            let result = bill * (1 + tip) / Double(numberOfPeople)
            finalResult = String(format: "%.2f", result)
        }
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToResult", sender: self)
        
    }
  
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToResult" {
            let destination = segue.destination as! ResultsViewController
            destination.result = finalResult
            destination.tip = Int(tip*100)
            destination.split = numberOfPeople
        }
    }
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let oldText = billTextField.text, let r = Range(range, in: oldText) else {
            return true
        }

        let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: r, with: string)
        let isNumeric = newText.isEmpty || (Double(newText) != nil)
        let numberOfDots = newText.components(separatedBy: ".").count - 1

        let numberOfDecimalDigits: Int
        if let dotIndex = newText.firstIndex(of: ".") {
            numberOfDecimalDigits = newText.distance(from: dotIndex, to: newText.endIndex) - 1
        } else {
            numberOfDecimalDigits = 0
        }

        return isNumeric && numberOfDots <= 1 && numberOfDecimalDigits <= 2
    }

}
```

I was searching internet around I tried lots of codes from OverFlow, and tried to change different things from a code by myself thinking that it would help, but unfortunately because I'm just starting to learn I am too close to the solution and too blind to understand and see that solution

Comment: It's comma, not coma